# memory heap corruption + GFlags tools but not result

Tags: c++, memory

I have a code in production which crash one/two times per day, since one week.
This crash is due to memory heap corruption

In order to discover what is going wrong in my application, I try to use GFlags.

I have activate page heap with GFlags (I have checked in windows registery that a entry for my application has been well created )

The application run under windows and I have developped it using MSCV2010.

I put the appliction in DEBUG mode in production and I use the feature "attach to process" inside microsoft visual stuio.

When the crash occur I have now the following call stack :

```
wow64!Wow64NotifyDebugger+0x9
wow64!Wow64KiRaiseException+0x172
wow64!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0xd6
wow64cpu!ServiceNoTurbo+0x28
wow64!RunCpuSimulation+0xa
wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x2ed
ntdll!LdrpInitialize+0x2aa
ntdll!KiUserApcDispatcher+0x15 (TrapFrame @ 00000000`03e3fb38)
kernel32!BaseThreadStartThunk
```

glurp...

It seems I am not more advanced in the resolution of my problem..

Any advices concerning the use of GFlags ?

More generally, what can I expect with GFlags which can tell me where is the bug in my application ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Hans Passant : Sorry but do you know, where I can't find application verifier executable ?

Comment: Type "download application verifier" in a google query and take the first hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this article helps: [32-bit stack traces from x64 complete dumps](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2009/02/06/32-bit-stack-traces-from-x64-complete-dumps/)
You can save a dump file using visual studio by using `Debug>Save dump as`
That dump file can then be opened in windbg.

Comment: indeed the callstack on my message is copy paste from windbg with "Save dump as" file , as input.But it seems I can't get more information than with visual studio's callstack